# How to visualize kernel generated by a trained convolutional neural network?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

I found the picture below:

[image]

which is shown in [this web page](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#vis)

I wonder how are this kind of images generated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This picture is made by printing out the weights of first layer filters, later in that course there's a [section](http://cs231n.github.io/understanding-cnn/) about visualizing the networks.

For higher layers printing out the weights may not make sense, there's a paper that might be useful [Visualizing Higher-Layer Features of a Deep Network](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Aaron_Courville/publication/265022827_Visualizing_Higher-Layer_Features_of_a_Deep_Network/links/53ff82b00cf24c81027da530.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

Each convolutional kernel is just a matrix N x M (weight matrix), thus you can simply plot it (each square in the above plot is a single convoluational matrix). Color ones are probably taken from 3-channel convolution, thus each is encoded as one color.

Comment: Do you have any references of that? Since the images in my question is somehow complicated, which means the kernel has to be very large. It looks like at least 10 by 10 kernel. However usually the kernel is 3 by 3 or 5 by 5.

Comment: I see what you're trying to say but it is a bit misleading. Each convolutional kernel is an NxWxH where N is the number of input channels. They are able to show the first layer because an RGB image is a 3-way tensor, which matches the first layer individual weight dimensions.